# Two directional cell inside collection view , how to get cell title?

Tags: ios, swift2, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Hello I want to get cell title inside `UICollectionView` , I have 1 cell inside `UICollectionView` cell have categories array when I click `UICollectionView` item I want to get cell title. My codes here.

View controller Cell

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var categories = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
}

extension ViewController : UITableViewDelegate { }

extension ViewController : UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
         return categories[section]

    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return categories.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! CategoryRow
       return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        print(indexPath.row)

    }

}

UICollectionView


import UIKit

class CategoryRow : UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
}

extension CategoryRow : UICollectionViewDataSource {


    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 12
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("videoCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! VideoCell
        return cell
    }

}

extension CategoryRow : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {


    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let itemsPerRow:CGFloat = 4
        let hardCodedPadding:CGFloat = 5
        let itemWidth = (collectionView.bounds.width / itemsPerRow) - hardCodedPadding
        let itemHeight = collectionView.bounds.height - (2 * hardCodedPadding)
        return CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)

    }


    //MARK :- UICollectionViewDelegate
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


    print(indexPath.row) // HERE gives collection view number when clicked BUT I WANT TO Get cell title which inside categories ARRAY example: A/3, B/5



    }




}
```

Bottom side I marked with

> print(indexPath.row) // HERE gives collection view number when clicked BUT I WANT TO Get cell title which inside categories ARRAY example: A/3, B/5

I want to see action there, thanks your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need add title protpery to your class

```
CategoryRow : UITableViewCell {
    var title: String?
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
}
```

and you need add method in `CategoryRow`

```
func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    title = nil
 }
```

in `ViewController` set this title to cell

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! CategoryRow
        let titleFromCategories = categories[indexPath.row] as? String
        cell.title = titleFromCategories
       return cell
    }
```

and in `CategoryRow` implement like below

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let yourString = title + String(format: "/%d", indexPath.row)

        print(yourString) // HERE gives collection view number when clicked BUT I WANT TO Get cell title which inside categories ARRAY example: A/3, B/5

 }
```

Comment: hello I did but when I clicked gives output like A/5,A/3,A/7, every cell gives A, but I clicked C, but gives all of them A

Comment: I forgot, you need add `prepareforReuse ` method in cell, updated answer

Comment: I added but same gives output all , A/2 like

Comment: My category row file topside edit thats :   class CategoryRow :  UITableViewCell {
    var title: String?
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        title = nil
    }

    }

Answer (score 1):

Get title from your array as follow:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
     let title = String(format: "%@/%d", categories[indexPath.row], indexPath.row) 
     print(title)
}
```

Comment: says error :  Use of unresolved identifier 'categories'